# MYSQL - Update row number for each group

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the column sip_count so that it counts the number of rows with the same sip_id as shown below. None of the things that I have tried are worth posting. How do I do this?

**Table**

```
sip_id | sip   | sip_count
--------------------------- 
 1      |  1    | 2
 1      |  1    | 2
 2      |  1    | 3
 2      |  1    | 3
 2      |  1    | 3
 4      |  1    | 2
 4      |  1    | 2
 3      |  1    | 3
 3      |  1    | 3
 3      |  1    | 3
```

**Desired result**

```
 sip_id | sip   | sip_count
--------------------------- 
 1      |  1    | 1
 1      |  1    | 2
 2      |  1    | 1
 2      |  1    | 2
 2      |  1    | 3
 4      |  1    | 1
 4      |  1    | 2
 3      |  1    | 1
 3      |  1    | 2
 3      |  1    | 3
```

Comment: with the same sip_ip or sip_id?

Comment: @mw509 I'm not sure what you mean. The sip_id should stay the way it is. I want to know how to update the column sip_count, so that it looks like shown above

Comment: @marcp Your do not show an sip_ip column but just an sip_id. I believe that is what mw509 is getting at.

Comment: Ohhhh misread that. I have edited it now ty :)

Comment: Which mysql version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 8.0.19

Comment: A primary key is advisable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mysql 8 you can use window function

```
SELECT 
 `sip_id`, `sip`,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `sip_id`) AS 'sip_count'
FROM sip_count
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sip_count (
>   `sip_id` INTEGER,
>   `sip` INTEGER,
>   `sip_count` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO sip_count
>   (`sip_id`, `sip`, `sip_count`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '2'),
>   ('1', '1', '2'),
>   ('2', '1', '3'),
>   ('2', '1', '3'),
>   ('2', '1', '3'),
>   ('4', '1', '2'),
>   ('4', '1', '2'),
>   ('3', '1', '3'),
>   ('3', '1', '3'),
>   ('3', '1', '3');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>  `sip_id`, `sip`,
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `sip_id`) AS 'sip_count'
> FROM sip_count
> ```
>
> ```
> sip_id | sip | sip_count
> -----: | --: | --------:
>      1 |   1 |         1
>      1 |   1 |         2
>      2 |   1 |         1
>      2 |   1 |         2
>      2 |   1 |         3
>      3 |   1 |         1
>      3 |   1 |         2
>      3 |   1 |         3
>      4 |   1 |         1
>      4 |   1 |         2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c489562379fa9ab2b5168c7c7741cf1a)*

Comment: I am kind of new to this and I can see that my desired result was misleading. I have edited it now to be the correct desired result

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This works thank you, but how do i turn it into UPDATE?

Comment: I am looking for to update the table. How do I do that? @nbk

Comment: Your rows have nothing unique, for update to grasp. Your design is flawed for  your purpose. Use INSERT .. INTO .. SELECT see above to create a new table delete the old one. You could also add a auto_increment to identify every Row by its id and use that to update.

Comment: Altered my table and got it to work. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Try to use variable:

```
SET @i:=0;
UPDATE 
    table_name 
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        table_name.primary_key, 
        table_name.sip_id, 
        @i:=IF(@i > b.count, 1, @i+1) AS count 
    FROM table_name 
    INNER JOIN 
        (
          SELECT 
            sip_id, 
            COUNT(sip_count) AS count 
          FROM table_name GROUP BY sip_id
        ) b 
    ON table_name.sip_id = b.sip_id
      ) c 
ON table_name.primary_key = c.primary_key 
SET sip_count=c.count
```

Comment: This gives me the total number of rows with the given sip_id in every row, but I would like to count up the number of rows

Comment: Do you mean that there would be only one row for each sip_id?

Comment: I have edited the post with what your suggestion did for my table

Comment: Oops maybe I got it wrong. So you want to have the result -  1|1|2   2|1|3   4|1|2   3|1|3 ?

Comment: You can see my desired result in the post. I have tried to clarify the post a little

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check if this helps :)

Comment: The table does not have a primary key :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below query and it gave me the result you are looking for.

```
UPDATE SipDetails 
SET sip_count = (SELECT (MAX(sp2.sip_count) + 1)
                FROM SipDetails sp2 
                WHERE sp2.sip_id = SipDetails.sip_id);
```

Please note:
[SipDetails] should be replaced with your relevant table name.

Below mentioned is the result of running the above query. 
I initially set the "sip_count" column value to 0 (zero), before the update.

[image]

Comment: I get this error running the query: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'SipDetails' for update in FROM clause –